# How to swipe more then 3 UIViews on one ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer, uiviewanimationtransition

i want to  swipe more than 3 views on one view controller using swipe Gesture.i am fresher on objective-c. this below code is to swipe 3 views only i want to swipe more views in sequence

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
    // creating custom First view and adding on view
    firstFiveQuesView=[[UIView alloc]init];
    firstFiveQuesView.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+54, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);

    firstFiveQuesView.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
    [self.view addSubview:firstFiveQuesView];

    UILabel  *Q1Label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    Q1Label.frame=CGRectMake(firstFiveQuesView.frame.origin.x+20, firstFiveQuesView.frame.origin.y,400, 20);
    Q1Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    Q1Label.text=@"Q1: qqewuiqy qoeyq ooghj  qyouiye o y";
    [firstFiveQuesView addSubview: Q1Label];

    // similarly second view created and added on main view...

    // similarly third view created and added on main view...

    // Swipe Gesture adding on the views

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    [firstFiveQuesView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [thirdFiveQuesView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

// swipe left or right below

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    // What we do write now:here
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
    }
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
    }
}
```

please help me with some samples and tutorials

Thanks in advance.....................

Comment: its better to add these 3 views in to one scrollView and set the contentOffset accordingly

Answer (score 0):

its better to add these 3 views in to one scrollView and set the contentOffset accordingly.then you can avoid adding of gestures.

Comment: but my requirement is to use swipe gesture only. Anyway thankq

Answer (score 0):

use 3 views in  `uiscrollView`  with page controller

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a class called `PageViewController`.

This  link  should surely help you out.

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial